# How correctly convert date time to moment format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using vuejs 2.6 I have a function to which I sent datetime in string format like : 2019-06-03 16:53:29 , convert it to 
moment format and next I converto to other string format, like:

```
momentDatetime(datetime, datetime_format, default_val) {

    let dt= datetime
    if (typeof datetime == "string") {
        if (datetime_format == "") return '';

        dt = Vue.moment(String(datetime));

    } // if (typeof datetime == "string") {
```

That works if datetime is string, now I want to send (current) datetime, like :

```
    item.created_at= this.momentDatetime( moment( new Date() ), this.settings_js_moment_datetime_format )
```

I failed with line above. How correctly convert date time to moment format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it with mixin method :
        momentDatetime(datetime, datetime_format, default_val) {

```
    if (typeof datetime == "object") {
        return  Vue.moment(datetime).format(datetime_format);
    }
```

and calling it :

```
    this.momentDatetime( Vue.moment(),
```

It works !